# Change ActiveCell in a loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file from a third party that I wrote a macro to manipulate.

The macro needs to grab a technician's name and insert it prior to each service 
listed in the row per client.

The excel file is set up as follows.

|RowID|ClientID|CLname|CFname|TLname|TFname|Location|date|Serv|ServDur|ServID|Cost|

Each row has 1 unique client, multiple technicians, each technician can have multiple services.

My macro runs with no errors, yet it makes no changes.

```
Sub UpdateText()
' UpdateText Macro
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+D

Dim fName As String
Dim lName As String
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCell As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim x As Long
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To LastRow
    LastCell = Range("IV1").End(xlToLeft).Column
    For x = 1 To LastCell
        If ActiveCell = "Location" Then
            lName = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Value
            fName = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Value Like "HC:H*" Then
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            ActiveCell.Value = lName
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = fName
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Select
        End If
    Next x
Next i

End Sub
```

The active cell doesn't move along with the For statement. Meaning the Active Cell is always A1.

Comment: Please try stepping through your code using F8 key to debug it and see what happens (or doesn't). Stepping through your code should at least allow you to describe where a specific failure mode occurs (e.g., evaluating an `If` statement should return `False` but it returns `True` instead and I can't figure out why, etc.).

Comment: RIght off the bat it's possible that your `lastRow` and `lastCell` are not what you think they are (step through & verify) and further complicating it is the fact that you're relying on `ActiveCell` while simultaneously inserting/shifting data in a loop, which seems immediately suspect.

Comment: The active cell doesn't move along with the For statement. Meaning the Active Cell is always A1. Other than ActiveCell what should I be using?

Comment: Which `For` statement? There are two of them. One (the inner one) provides a condition whereby the active cell is offset (0,3). The outer `For` statement never changes the active row. I suggest revising this code to avoid reliance on `ActiveCell`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without changing anything structurally in your code it seems like you need to change the `ActiveCell` along with the `For i` loop:

```
For i = 1 To LastRow
    LastCell = Range("IV1").End(xlToLeft).Column
    For x = 1 To LastCell
        If ActiveCell = "Location" Then
            lName = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Value
            fName = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Value Like "HC:H*" Then
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            ActiveCell.Value = lName
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = fName
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Select
        End If
    Next x
    Cells(i, 1).Select  '## Change your "ActiveCell" to the first cell in the next row.
Next i
```

This may yet not work 100% of the time because it's relying on `ActiveCell` and further, it's not explicitly *activating* anything, so that means it must rely on whatever the user had previously selected/activated before running the macro. This is unreliable, at best, because people forget to select the correct cell, etc...

Further: relying on `ActiveCell` leads to spaghetti code that becomes increasingly difficult to read, interpret, or troubleshoot (especially as you start working across multiple worksheets, workbooks, etc.) and defeats the purpose of object-oriented programming. [Learn to use and manipulate the objects directly, and you'll find that it's very rarely (like, 0.01% of the time) necessary to `Select` or `Activate` anything:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

```
Dim cl as Range '# Declaring a Range object to represent a cell on which to operate

For i = 1 To LastRow
    LastCell = Range("IV1").End(xlToLeft).Column
    For x = 1 To LastCell
        Set cl = Cells(i, x)   '## Assign your cell: row:=i, column:=x
        If cl.Value = "Location" Then
            lName = cl.Offset(0, -2).Value
            fName = cl.Offset(0, -1).Value
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Value Like "HC:H*" Then
            cl.Resize(1,2).Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            cl.Value = lName
            cl.Offset(0, 1).Value = fName
            Set cl = cl.Offset(0, 3)
        End If
    Next x
    Set cl = Cells(i, 1).Select 
Next i
```

You may also want to review this for more reliable ways of obtaining the "last" row or column:

[Error in finding last used cell in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba)

Comment: It's worth noting, in order for it to work with your changes, while doing what i needed it to do, I had to add 2 to both LastCell and X.

Comment: You can do that easily and optimally using `For i = 1 to LastRow Step 3` and `For x = 1 to LastCell Step 3` (instead of having to increment like `x = x +2` inside the loop.  Cheers.